# Getting point mouse interaction and brushes to work together

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I'm trying to get mouse events to cooperate between different elements in a scatterplot.  D3's `brush` component adds some listeners to the called element (e.g. `svg.call(brush)`).  I also want to display points bound on the SVG, much like a scatterplot, and for those points to support `mouseover` events (for tooltips and other interactions).

A [previous solution](http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/11/D3-brush-and-tooltip.html) suggests drawing points before calling the brush, which supports mouseover on points while allowing the brush to be drawn and the extent modified.  However, if the dragging motion for the brush starts upon a point (which I anticipate in very dense graphs), the brush component misbehaves when an extent is already active (translating the brush resizes the extent instead).  You can try it out on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/yelper/d38ddf461a0175ebd927946d15140947), where the above suggested solution has been implemented.

[image: Failed solution example]

I've narrowed the issue to how the event is handled in d3's `brushstart()` function, internal to the `d3.svg.brush` component.  Here's what relevant variables look like when the brush is correctly working.

```
                     this           eventTarget                           dragging   resizing  
                     -------------- ------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- 
Translating extent   brush parent   rect.extent                           true       0         
Resizing extent      brush parent   rect (invisible rects for resizing)   false      e.g. "e"  
Redrawing            brush parent   rect.background                       false      0
```

This is what it looks like currently, with the solution above:

```
                      this           eventTarget   dragging   resizing        
-------------------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ---------------- 
 Translating extent   brush parent   circle        false      circle.datum()  
 Resizing extent      brush parent   circle        false      circle.datum()  
 Redrawing            brush parent   circle        false      circle.datum()
```

The real question is: how can I fudge the source of d3.event.target to match the first table?  If I can do that, I can get the behavior I want.  Thanks for any help!

If you've missed it, here's a bl.ock of this conundrum in action: http://bl.ocks.org/yelper/d38ddf461a0175ebd927946d15140947

Comment: In the case of a empty brush being started on a circle you could just do something like this: http://blockbuilder.org/larsenmtl/2862c433899f63456f5279e4a6281f5e, doesn't fix the move started from a circle though.

Comment: What if the data in the brush displayed instead of mouse hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick hack which corrects the behavior:

```
.on('mousedown', function(d){
    var e = brush.extent(),
      m = d3.mouse(svg.node()), // pointer position with respect to g
      p = [x.invert(m[0]), y.invert(m[1])]; // position in user space

  if ( brush.empty() || // if there is no brush
       (e[0][0] > d[0] || d[0] > e[1][0]
       || e[0][1] > d[1] || d[1] > e[1][1] ) // or our current circle is outside the bounds of the brush
  ) {
    brush.extent([p,p]); // set brush to current position
  } else {
    d3.select(this).classed('extent', true); // else we are moving the brush, so fool d3 (I got this from looking at source code, it's how d3 determines a drag)
  }
});
```

Working code below, updated block [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/4c5ebcc9bca489f8f530bd163b35f39b).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .hidden {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    
    
    .extent {
        fill: #000;
        fill-opacity: .125;
        stroke: #fff;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
    
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, 10]);
    
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 10]);
    
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
    
var curPt = d3.select('body')
    .append('p')
    .html("Current point: ")
    .append('span')
        .attr('id', 'curPt');
    
var svg = d3.select('body').insert('svg', 'p')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
    
svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,'+height+')')
    .call(xAxis);
    
svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);
    
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .on("brush", function() {
        var e = brush.extent(),
           c = svg.selectAll('circle');
       c.classed('extent', false);
        c.classed('hidden', function(d) {
            return e[0][0] > d[0] || d[0] > e[1][0]
                || e[0][1] > d[1] || d[1] > e[1][1];
            }
        );
    })
    .on("brushend", function() {
        if (brush.empty()) svg.selectAll('circle').classed('hidden', false);
    });
    
svg.call(brush);
    
var data = d3.range(50).map(function() { return [Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10]; });

svg.append('g') 
    .attr('class', 'points')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data).enter()
  .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', 'steelblue')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        curPt.html("[" + d[0] + ", " + d[1] + "]");
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        curPt.html("");
    })
  .on('mousedown', function(d){
    var e = brush.extent(),
          m = d3.mouse(svg.node()),
          p = [x.invert(m[0]), y.invert(m[1])];
       
      if ( brush.empty() || 
           (e[0][0] > d[0] || d[0] > e[1][0]
           || e[0][1] > d[1] || d[1] > e[1][1] )   
      ) {
        brush.extent([p,p]);
      } else {
        d3.select(this).classed('extent', true);
      }
    });

    
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!  That's definitely the behavior I want.  

I started going along another road this weekend, ended up with something like this block, but it requires two clicks on a point to work: https://bl.ocks.org/yelper/dc2bbff489dbf0820ccf8d73537f071c... I'd be curious what's missing from this example to get it to work.

Comment: @yelper, your approach looks sound but it doesn't seem like `d3` picks up on your re-dispatched mousedown event.  I tried using the `d3.event` and dispatching that to the `rect.background` (instead of creating a new event) but that doesn't work either....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/paradite/rpqusqdc/2/

Basically I used my previously coded range selection tool using `drag` event instead of `brush`: http://bl.ocks.org/paradite/71869a0f30592ade5246

It does not interfere with your circles. So you just need to get the current `rect` dimensions and update your circles accordingly:

```
  // select your points here
  var e = selectionRect.getCurrentAttributes();
  svg.selectAll('circle').classed('hidden', function(d) {
    return e.x1 > x(d[0]) || x(d[0]) > e.x2 || e.y1 > y(d[1]) || y(d[1]) > e.y2;
  });
```

Of course you can remove parts of its logic as much of it is not necessary for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  However, it doesn't look like hovering over points works within the rectangle, and one is unable to drag (translate) the rectangle around.

Comment: I fixed the `mouseover` issue, the `drag` feature is something that my code doesn't implement, if you need it maybe you can try to code it?